# css hover menu, close dropdown when same element is touched again on iPads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The navbar contains categories like:

```
politics, economy, education
```

when you click on these categories, a dropdown opens with locations like:

```
asia, europe, North America
```

So what I want is:

If the user clicks (tabs), (or hover on desktops) for example on category: Politics, the dropdown opens normally, but if the user clicks (tabs) on the same category name (Politics) the dropdown is closed.

Is that possible?

Here is my HTML

```css
#menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #121212;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.categories:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
}

.categories .touch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.categories .touch:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
}

.categories .touch:before {
  content: "▪ ";
}

.locations {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.locations a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-left: 1px solid #121212;
  border-right: 1px solid #121212;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
}

.locations a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #121212;
}

.categories:hover .locations {
  display: block;
  animation: santiaborg 555ms ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

@keyframes santiaborg {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0) translateX(-50%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.1) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="menu" class="active">
  <div class="categories" tabindex="1">
    <div class="touch">News</div>
    <div class="locations">
      <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
      <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
      <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
      <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
      <a href="link.html">North America</a>
      <a href="link.html">South America</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="categories" tabindex="2">
    <div class="touch">Politics</div>
    <div class="locations">
      <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
      <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
      <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
      <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
      <a href="link.html">North America</a>
      <a href="link.html">South America</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="categories" tabindex="3">
    <div class="touch">Economy</div>
    <div class="locations">
      <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
      <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
      <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
      <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
      <a href="link.html">North America</a>
      <a href="link.html">South America</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added one more CSS class `hide-item` to toggle the dropdown open and close and wrote some JavaScript codes to handle that click event. If you have any question regarding the JS codes you can ask.

I also updated the CSS with your codes so that the CSS class `hide-item` will only exist in non-hoverable devices.

And the exact same way I added conditional rendering for the JS codes as well so that those codes will only be executed on non-hoverable devices.

```js
// Conditionally rendering only for non-hoverable devices
if(window.matchMedia("(hover: none)").matches){
  var categories = document.querySelectorAll('.categories');
  var locations = document.querySelectorAll('.locations');
  
  for(i=0; i<categories.length; i++){

    categories[i].addEventListener('click', function(){        
      this.children[1].classList.toggle('hide-item');

      this.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
        this.children[1].classList.remove('hide-item');
      })          
    })        
  }
}
```

```css
@media (hover: none){
  /* This class will only exist when hover is not possible (Tablet or mobile devices) */
  .hide-item{
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
   #menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #121212;
  background-color: inherit;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 8;
}

.categories {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.categories:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
}

.categories .touch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 42px;
  line-height: 42px;
}

.categories .touch:hover {
  color: #e5633f;
}

.categories .touch:before {
  content: "▪ ";
}

.locations {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.locations a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  border-left: 1px solid #121212;
  border-right: 1px solid #121212;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #121212;
}

.locations a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #121212;
}

.categories:hover .locations {
  display: block;
  animation: santiaborg 555ms ease-in-out forwards;
  transform-origin: top center;
}

@keyframes santiaborg {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(0) translateX(-50%);
  }
  80% {
    transform: scaleY(1.1) translateX(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scaleY(1) translateX(-50%);
  }
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="menu" class="active">
    <div class="categories" tabindex="1">
      <div class="touch">News</div>
      <div class="locations">
        <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
        <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
        <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
        <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
        <a href="link.html">North America</a>
        <a href="link.html">South America</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="categories" tabindex="2">
      <div class="touch">Politics</div>
      <div class="locations">
        <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
        <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
        <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
        <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
        <a href="link.html">North America</a>
        <a href="link.html">South America</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="categories" tabindex="3">
      <div class="touch">Economy</div>
      <div class="locations">
        <a href="link.html">Europe</a>
        <a href="link.html">Asia</a>
        <a href="link.html">Africa</a>
        <a href="link.html">Oceania</a>
        <a href="link.html">North America</a>
        <a href="link.html">South America</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a question: it does exactly what I want, but I want that function to be enabled only on touch devices because on desktops people is use to use hover functions. To enable this only for touch devices I was thinking to add the following: @media (hover: none) {
.hide-item{display:none !important;}
} to detect it, but I am not sure if this is the best option. Any suggestion? By the way, thank you very very much Rakibul because it is working fine

Comment: I found an error: so we click on category "politics" to open it, now we click on it again and it closes. But now if we click it again to open it again, it no longer opens

Comment: OK, I fixed this one and thinking about the other one.  Instead of adding the class now I changed it to `toggle`. Now it is fixed :)

Comment: I also updated the CSS with your codes so that the CSS class `hide-item` will only exist in non-hoverable devices. 
And the exact same way I added conditional rendering for the JS codes as well so that those codes will only be executed on non-hoverable devices.

Comment: Codepen is telling me there is a semicolon missing in the Javascript, I am new to Javascript so I really don't know where I have to put the missing semicolon

Comment: Maybe it is because of the improper indentation. No semicolon is missing. I checked several times and no warning from my editors as well. Here is a link: https://jsfiddle.net/ajr068w3/